# point a href link to more information in same template django

Tags: django, templates, variables, href

Hi i am quite new to django (not python though), and i am writing a small webapp for our company which basically:
1) either searches our customers by search form
2) search by 2 drop down menus - 1st one is organisation, 2nd one is specific customer
3) it is connected to our OTRS mysql database, and reads customer info from table customer_user - got this part covered
Currently i created a webpage, and got search form and search results covered with results. Problem i have is i imagined that results will be only first_name and last_name part of the table. After that, if i click the link, it will open more info. Now this is a part that i am stuck on. I don't know how to point the link, to just add more things on same web page. I think i am missing the correct syntax in the link alone + another function in views file.
Anyway, here are my files:

models.py

```
class CustomerUser(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
login = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
email = models.CharField(max_length=150)
customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
pw = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
fax = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
mobile = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
street = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
zip = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
comments = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
valid_id = models.IntegerField()
create_time = models.DateTimeField()
create_by = models.IntegerField()
change_time = models.DateTimeField()
change_by = models.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'customer_user'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import CustomerUser
from django.http import HttpResponse

def search_form(request):
    #global request
    return render(request, 'korisnici.html')

def search(request):
    global q

    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        korisnik = CustomerUser.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=q)
        korisnik1 = CustomerUser.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=q)
        if korisnik:
            return render(request, 'rezultati.html', {'korisnik': korisnik, 'query': q})
        elif korisnik1:
            return render(request, 'rezultati.html', {'korisnik1': korisnik1, 'query': q})
    else:
        return render(request, 'korisnici.html', {'error': True})

def rezultat(request):
    global q
    if q:
        #q = request.GET['q']
        korisnik = CustomerUser.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=q)
        korisnik1 = CustomerUser.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=q)
        if korisnik:
            return render(request, 'rezultat.html', {'korisnik': korisnik, 'query': q})
        elif korisnik1:
            return render(request, 'rezultat.html', {'korisnik1': korisnik1, 'query': q})
    else:
        return render(request, 'korisnici.html', {'error': True})
```

and templates file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MAI KORISNICI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Pretraži">
    </form>
    <p>Ključna riječ: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if korisnik %}
    <p>Pronađeno je {{ korisnik|length }} trgovina.</p>
    <ul>
        {% for book in korisnik %}
        <li><a href={{ rezultat}}>{{ book.first_name }} {{ book.last_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% elif korisnik1 %}
    <p>Pronađeno je {{ korisnik1|length }} trgovina.</p>
    <ul>
        {% for book in korisnik1 %}
        <li><a href="placeholder">{{ book.first_name }} {{ book.last_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Nijedan korisnik ne zadovoljava Vaš upit.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is this part i think:

```
{% for book in korisnik1 %}
        <li><a href="placeholder">{{ book.first_name }} {{ book.last_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

I don't know how to retrieve a variable from that particular result i click on and retrieve/show more information about that customer from the same database (so not only first_name and last_name, but also email, pw, comments,...).

I am currently on 7th chapter of www.djangobook.com and i am kinda getting frustrated...i can't seem to find how this particular part is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Django issue - you are passing in the CustomerUser instance to the template, so the info is all there. You just need a little javascript to show all the results when the click event is fired for that link. Just store them in a div, hide it by default, and show on click.

Comment: That seems like an idea. My problem is my web design knowlegde is tied to css basics, hence my not knowing this :). I guess google will help :)